# Sql Query to get Data based on Current Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two parameters to pass the values of date and time one as start and other as end time.I want to pass the value to start time with specific date like (1/1/2014) and for other end date I would like to pass the current date for my below query .Can any one help how can I pass the current date to the query

```
select * into #temp from 
dbo.fnDashboard_DummyWeekly1(
dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, '5/28/2014'), 0),
dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, '6/6/2014'), 0)
)
```

Comment: `convert(date,getdate())` will give you today's date.

Comment: dbo.fnDashboard_DummyWeekly1('20140101', GETDATE())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
select * into #temp from 
dbo.fnDashboard_DummyWeekly1(
dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, '5/28/2014'), 0),
convert(date,getdate())
)
```